# Have trouble understanding a python function

Tags: python, function

I am working with someone else's code and they have defined this function:

```
def QExpr (name):
    length = len(name)
    code = name [length-10:]
    exp='"TOWN_ID"='+ str(int(code[1:4]))
    return exp
```

I don't quite understand what this function does. I just know that it is used to calculate a value using a table in a database. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Now is a great opportunity to learn to use your debugger.  You can run this function, step through each line, and inspect the values of variables to see exactly what it is doing and how it works.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Which bit, exactly, are you having trouble with?

Comment: This code is pretty straightforward; the only tricky thing is the [list slicing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/3282436).

Comment: Thanks. I cannot run it since this is actually inside an ArcGIS model that I am trying to understand. A bunch of previous steps cannot be ran. So I need to understand this function in order to squeeze what it's trying to do inside some other lines.

Comment: I am very new to python - trying to understand what exp='"TOWN_ID"='+ str(int(code[1:4])) actually does.

Comment: Everyone, thanks a lot. Can anyone tell me in a few sentences what this does? Again - I don't really know python

Comment: Find out what each of those functions do. 0x5453 has already given you a link about list slicing syntax. These things are easy to find with a quick google search, and you'll probably find lots of answers already on Stack Overflow. [Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953), and [explain my code to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468/843953) is too broad for SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like it does the same as this code:

```
def Qexpr(name):
    return '"TOWN_ID"=' + str(int(name[-9:-5]))
```

for example "TOWN_ID"=3245

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my silly question!

Comment: Thanks too, I needed some reputation